# ReferenceError: browser is not defined - Using Karma and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am getting `ReferenceError: browser is not defined` when trying to set up some basic tests with Jasmine and Karma.

Here is my Karma config file

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Mar 08 2017 13:29:09 GMT+0000 (GMT)

module.exports = function(config) {
   config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        './spec/**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-    preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

And then I have one test file called `loginSpec.js` shown here:

```
describe('login page', function() {

    beforeEach(function(){
        browser().navigateTo('/');
    });

    it('should have the correct title', function() {
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Title');

    });
});
```

Whenever I run the test in the Karma tool window I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: browser is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (spec/loginSpec.js:11:9)
ReferenceError: browser is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (spec/loginSpec.js:15:16)
```

I don't understand why browser is suddenly not defined as I had tests working before setting up Karma (using WebdriverIO and selenium-standalone). These tests were written in the same way and there were no errors regarding `browser`

I have also researched and found that a lot of other people have had the same issue, but they are having it because of issues with Angular, which i am not using?

Answer (score 0):

Using karma,jasmine there is no handler/object as `browser` available like WebdriverIO and selenium-standalone.

If you are looking to write a unit test case using jasmine to test the route, it can be done via injecting `$location` service of angular as below:

```
describe('login page', function() {

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject((_$rootScope_, _$location_) => {
       _$location_.path('/');
       _$rootScope_.$digest();
    }));

    it('should have the correct title', function() {
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Title');

    });
});
```

Comment: The reason I cant use $location is because I am not using Angular in my app

Comment: @CGrant Ok. Can you tell me what are you trying to achieve/test by navigating to '/' in the unit test ?

Comment: I was initially trying to test things such as 'it should log in with valid credentials' and 'it should not log in with invalid credentials' etc. However after a lot of research I think I have learnt that I am going about testing my app the wrong way. I should be testing the functions in the `routes` folder, and it seems to do this I should be using **mocha** (or a similar framework) with jasmine in order to test my node.js routes.